# How can i resize/restrict a folder for users like Desktop/Downloads in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, directory, quota

I want to enable size restrictions, which means I want to resize few folders for users like Desktop, Downloads or Music folders. If a user exceeded the memory then it shouldn't overwrite and gets the warning message.

How to resize the folders through Ansible ? It's for many hosts and directly on the system with root permission. I want to do this on Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop edition.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to set a quota on their home directories and let them figure out what they want to save where, rather than monitoring all the sub directories. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-user-and-group-quotas and https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/disk-quota/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Panther, i have one more doubt, if I will implement quota for the home directory will that impact to the hidden folders ( like if someone uses thunderbird for mailing and the file location is /home/.thunderbird which is hidden ) if yes then how to figure out not to impact the hidden folders

Comment: Yes it will affect hidden directories. Look, you can either set a quota per user per directory (lots of work) or set a reasonable quota for all of home (much less work). Hidden directories should not be *that* large .

Comment: I can understand that qquota per user per directory is a big headache, actually, my users are using thunderbird and few more directories about 20/30 GBs. so I don't want  to restrict any of the hidden directories, I just want to restrict few directories with lesser memory. Please tell me if its possible@Panther

Answer (score 2):

Based on the accepted answer at [How to set limit on directory size in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8148831/3701431) by [Sergei Nikulov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/350527/sergei-nikulov) and the [original tutorial](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/directory-quota-601140/), I've put together a script which can create a quota-limited directory on demand.

The script operates on the premise of creating a loop device with specific size and filesystem, and mounting the loop device at the user-defined directory.

#### Script

Also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/mklimdir.sh). Further development will be done there.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: June 1, 2018
# Written for: https://askubuntu.com/q/1043035/295286
# Based on: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/directory-quota-601140/

set -e

print_usage(){

cat <<EOF
Usage: sudo mklimdir.sh -m <Mountpoint Directory> -f <Filesystem> -s <INT>

-m directory
-f filesystem type (one of supported by mke2fs)
-s size in bytes
-h this message

Exit statuses:
0:
1: Invalid option
2: Missing argument
3: No args
4: root privillege required
EOF
} > /dev/stderr

parse_args(){
    #set -x

    option_handler(){

        case ${opt} in
            m) mountpoint=$( realpath -e "${OPTARG}" );;
            s) size=${OPTARG} ;;
            h) print_usage; exit 0 ;;
            f) mkfs_cmd=mkfs."${OPTARG}" ;;
            \?) echo ">>>Invalid option: -$OPTARG" > /dev/stderr; exit 1;;
            \:) echo ">>>Missing argument to -${OPTARG}" > /dev/stderr; exit 2;;
        esac
    }

    local OPTIND opt
    getopts "m:s:f:h" opt || { echo "No args passed">/dev/stderr;print_usage;exit 3;}
    option_handler 
    while getopts "m:s:f:h" opt; do
         option_handler
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))

}


main(){

    if [ $EUID -ne 0 ]; then
        echo ">>> Please run the script with sudo/as root" > /dev/stderr
        exit 4
    fi

    local mountpoint=""
    local size=0
    local mkfs_cmd

    parse_args "$@"
    quota_fs=/"${mountpoint//\//_}"_"$(date +%s)".quota
    dd if=/dev/zero of="$quota_fs" count=1 bs="$size"
    "$mkfs_cmd" "$quota_fs"
    mount -o loop,rw,usrquota,grpquota "$quota_fs" "$mountpoint"

    chown $SUDO_USER:$SUDO_USER "$mountpoint"

}

main "$@"
```

#### Usage

There's 3 required flags:

- `-m` for mountpoint, aka the directory which you want to limit
- `-s` the size to which you want to limit in bytes
- `-f` filesystem. If you're not sure what this should be, just stick with ext4 or ext3

Here's an example of how I used this script to create `./quoted_dir` limited to 1 MiB (that is 1024<sup>2</sup> in [Binary Prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix) )

```
sudo ./mklimdir.sh -m ./quoted_dir/ -s $((1024*1024)) -f ext4
```

I've tested the script with `while true; do cat /etc/passwd >> ./quoted_dir/passwd; sleep 1; done` type of loop, which would append contents of `/etc/passwd` to the file inside the quote-limited directory.  The `cat` eventually errored out with:

```
cat: write error: No space left on device
```

and the file writing stopped at 909KiB which is just a little short of 1 MiB and would prevent exceeding the limits within the directory.

#### Further development

For permanent effect, the loop device created by the script [should be added to `/etc/fstab`](https://superuser.com/a/1105577/418028). This may be added later on GitHub. The script operates on a single directory, however this script can be used within another script for creating multiple limited directories, so it is flexible enough.

Comment: Just for my understanding: this means when I want 20 directories with quotas then I'll need 20 filesystems and they pre-occupy 20×$size, i.e. the quota is also the guaranteed size, not just the max. size, right?

Comment: @PerlDuck  Yes, It means 20 filesystems per each folder. I'm not sure what do you mean about guaranteed vs max.size, though.